# Reading only 1 char then using method from String in java

Tags: java, regex, file

In my task I need to read this input 1,2,3. I read it from file.

```
String listOfNumbers=  reader.readLine();
listOfNumbers= listOfNumbers.replace(",", " ");

for (int i = 0; i< listOfNumbers.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(listOfNumbers.charAt(i)))
        System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
}
```

Output is always 1 2 3 but I want for every number to send it to function.

E.g.

if (listOfNumbers) =1 then send it to function.

if (listOfNumbers) = 2 ....

I mean if listOfNumber equals some number.

My friend did it with regex but I didn't find right solutio.

Comment: what means _"send it to function"_ ?

Comment: Just pass it to the function what's the problem?

Comment: When I print lifOfNumbers it prints 1 2 3, I need for every number in that list to send it to function

Answer (score 0):

you can split the String like so:

```
val members = listOfNumbers.split(",")
```

And then you have each individual number separately in the List `members` and you can pass them as parameters to whatever function you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an array of string with the method Split() is easier to work with